# Vector tile generation

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, vector

I have a full planet imported in PostgreSQL with imposm3.

What is the best way to generate vector tiles (MVT in .mbtiles) from PBF/PostgreSQL with maximum hardware utilization (distributed generation to multiple CPUs/cores)?

Comment: Some hints about MVT are mentioned at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles ... but I cannot give you detailed advice on my own.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found [tilerator](https://github.com/kartotherian/kartotherian/blob/master/packages/tilerator/README.md) as the best solution.

Comment: Why is it best? what other options/software were there that you compared it with? Did you do any bench-marking?